# flatten Map in Map structure with stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following structure in HashMaps (not all the values are maps (see id) and there are more levels embedded):

```
{ 
  "id":"0",
  "name":{  
      "title":"Mr.",
      "personName": {
          "firstName":"Boot",
          "familyName":"Strap"
      }
   }
}
```

Can I flatten it with Java 8 stream like

```
{ 
  "id":"0",
  "name.title":"Mr.",
  "name.personName.firstName":"Boot",
  "name.personName.familyName":"Strap"
}
```

?

Comment: Can you share the Java structure ?

Comment: That is a recursive structure, and streams cannot do recursive operations. Write a recursive method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Streams` does not do recursive computation, you may use classic way like

```
static Map<String, String> flatten(Map<String, Object> map, String prefix) {
    prefix = prefix.isEmpty() ? prefix : prefix + ".";
    Map<String, String> res = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map) {
            res.putAll(flatten((Map) entry.getValue(), prefix + entry.getKey()));
        } else {
            res.put(prefix + entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Stream way will look like

```
static Map<String, String> flatten(Map<String, Object> map, String p) {
    final String prefix = p.isEmpty() ? p : p + ".";
    return map.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .map(e -> {
                  if (e.getValue() instanceof Map) {
                      return (Set<Map.Entry<String, String>>) flatten((Map) e.getValue(), prefix + e.getKey()).entrySet();
                  } else {
                      return Map.of(prefix + e.getKey(), e.getValue().toString()).entrySet();
                  }
              })
              .flatMap(Set::stream)
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

---

And use as

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Object> map = Map.of("id", 0, "name", Map.of("title", "Mr.", "personName", Map.of("firstName", "Boot", "familyName", "Strap")));
    Map<String, String> res = flatten(map, "");
    res.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
}

name.title=Mr.
name.personName.familyName=Strap
name.personName.firstName=Boot
id=0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple not using `Streams`, but use recursion:

```
public static Map<String, String> flatten(Map<String, Object> map) {
    return flatten("", map, new LinkedHashMap<>());
}

private static Map<String, String> flatten(String parent, Map<String, Object> map, Map<String, String> res) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = parent.isEmpty() ? entry.getKey() : parent + '.' + entry.getKey();

        if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map)
            flatten(key, (Map<String, Object>)entry.getValue(), res);
        else
            res.put(key, String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
    }

    return res;
}
```

**P.S.** I know that string concatenation in loop is not good (it is better to use `StringBuilder` or even `Deque`), but I use `String` to make this example more clear.